# New page shows unwanted indentation in Jasper Reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using Jasper reports to generate a pdf document. The first line of each paragraph is indented. When a paragraph overflows into the next page the first line in the new page is indented, even if it shouldn't be because it is just a continuation from the other page. Here is an example of a paragraph:

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="60" width="367" height="1">
    </reportElement>
    <textElement textAlignment="Justified">
        <font fontName="Arial" size="12"/>
        <paragraph lineSpacing="1_1_2" firstLineIndent="40"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["This is an extremely long paragraph, so long that it overflows into the next page and gets wrongly indented.\n"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

I know this is not a stack overflow but still it is an overflow problem. Any ideas?

PS: I am desperate, I will consider even the craziest ideas. Sorry, I have no idea why the xml did not keep the readable indented format. It seems that the indent pops up only where you don't want it.

Comment: (fwiw, questions don't have to be related to stack overflows)

Comment: :) it was a joke, hoping that being funny would help me get an answer. And indeed I got one from you :)